# Accessing my fingerprint password protected laptop after HP Client Security was removed

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I bought a new HP Probook 450 laptop with HP Client Security and fingerprint scanner. I used my fingerprint as a password; the laptop came with Windows 7 which I updated to Windows 8. HP Client Security was removed from my computer during this upgrade, but the fingerprint password remained so now I can't get into my computer. I searched on the web for methods of installing HP Client Security, but I couldn't find a working method.

Does anyone have a way in which I can gain access to my computer?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [an offline password reset boot disk](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/). You should be able to clear the administrator password and then login as administrator to do any necessary repairs.

Comment: it require the password befor starting windows:/

Comment: Switch it off, boot from CD and reset the password. You do not need to know any passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to SafeMode and try to remove the password. After BIOS splash screen, hold down the Shift key and repeatedly hit the F8 key. Doing so should get you to the recovery mode, but it might take a few tries before you achieve that. Hit the Troubleshoot button and Advanced options then. You need to restart your PC, after which you’ll see the familiar Advanced Boot Option screen

Go to settings and remove or simply change the password